# Is there any option to save a filter in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tag-search

I would like to save a filter (i don't want to type it every time) like this:

[javascript] -[html] -[css] -[angular] -[jquery] -[d3.js] -[android] -[webview] -[angularjs]

Is it possible in stack overflow?

Comment: Did you try clicking "Save"?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i didn't find this option

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the **Save** button to the right of the tag filter to create a new search tab:

[image: screenshot of home page]